# How to download files from MediaFire directly on iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad

I'm trying to download a .mp3 file from MediaFire on my Apple iPad, but whenever I click on "Download" button, a new tab opens and it plays the file.

I need to store this file in my iTunes instead of playing it, is that possible? Please note that I do not have access to a computer and I do not want to jailbreak my iPad.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to download an mp3 file from a site like MediaFire and place it directly in the Music app on your iPad.

There are some app where you can download a file to listen it later, sorry i don't know the name of one of those apps.

The options you have are

- to download it on a computer and sync your iPad
- to jailbreak your device and use iFile to access the mp3 file

Comment: An example might be dropbox, I use it to download files for later use.